# Using JPA, JavaFX and Maven, error of NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence Intellij

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I did a Maven project and I use the JavaFX style in Intellij IDEA, I had all the jar necessary to run my project and when I execute in IDE everything works perfectly but when I build the jar file and run appear this error:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code and the error *as text*.

Comment: so if NoClassDefFound then don't you think it would be nice to know what dependencies you are including at runtime?

Comment: Yeahh but I thought that when I build my final jar all the dependencies are included in packing but I needed change some jar locations. But is weird because when I just execute in IDE the code works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just package your code and not dependencies into your jar. So the dependencies are not in the classpath when you just run your jar file.

There are different ways of how to package the application. For example create an exe or add the necessary jars to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem... I realized that needed put some jar files, like persistence in resources/META-INF. I don't know explain why when I build my final jar from Intellij the packing doesn't add some dependencies. Thanks for explanation